# ERROR: could not insert module Invalid module format

Tags: c, linux, kernel-module, insmod

root@vm# insmod ./test01.ko

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./tes01.ko: Invalid module format
```

my c file test01.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading test01 module\n");
}
```

module based test01.c

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init load_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello World!");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit unload_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Unloading test01 module\n");
}

module_init(load_module);
module_exit(unload_module);
```

Makefile

```
obj-m += test01.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

make works fine
output of modinfo

```
root@vm$ modinfo test01.ko
filename:       /test01/test01.ko
srcversion:     5AF577C6F26F6B146320283
depends:        
vermagic:       4.0.0-rc5+ SMP mod_unload modversions
```

my kernel version uname -a

```
3.19.0-rc1+
```

dmseg output

```
[ 1470.217197] test01: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

I feel problem is my vermagic from modinfo is 4.0 while kernel version is 3.19. Some time back I compiled kernel source(don't know which) and also install it by `make -j2 && sudo make modules_install`

I don't know why there is mismatch in kernel version ?

Comment: after insert failed, what `dmesg` said?

Comment: @user1034749 I'll take a look and update the question.

Comment: I cann't see `dmesg` output, plus how you tell the kernel that `init_module` function should be called on start of module, you should use `module_init` and friends macroses

Comment: @user1034749 Added dmseg output as well as tried with module based macro, still same error.

Comment: It looks like your `/lib/modules/3.19.0-rc1+/build` is actually refers to the build directory of the kernel `4.0.0-rc5+`. E.g., you build and install kernel `3.19.0-rc1+`, remove sources(and build directory), get kernel `4.0.0-rc5+` in the same directory and build it.